# Swap two check boxes values

Tags: checkbox

I have 2 check boxes. I want to uncheck when I check the other and vice-versa. So , always, I'll have only one checked and the other unchecked. What I'm having now is when I check one, the other is unchecked (good). Now, when I go to the unchecked and check it, both become unchecked in the first click. Here is my example:

```
def CB1Function():

CB2.setChecked(0)
CB1.stateChanged.connect(CB1Function)

def CB2Function():

CB1.setChecked(0)
CB2.stateChanged.connect(CB2Function)
```

In other words, for example, I have 3 options with 3 checkboxes, I'm supposed to select only one option at a time.

Thanks

Comment: sounds to me like a radiobutton would be a better solution.
what are you using? c++, c#, java,...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a silly answer but why not use radiobuttons?

> A radio button or option button is a type of graphical user interface element that allows the user to choose only one of a predefined set of options.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_button

Comment: Thanks.
Solved with radio button.
def CB1Function():
    CB2.setChecked(0)
CB1.clicked.connect(CB1Function)

def CB2Function():
    CB1.setChecked(0)
CB2.clicked.connect(CB2Function)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a radiobutton indeed. But if you insist on checkboxes, try something like this:

```
        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkBox2.Checked = !checkBox1.Checked;
        }

        private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = !checkBox2.Checked;
        }
```

EDIT: if you have more then two checkboxes (and even with two) you could make a procedure that loops through all checkboxes and changes them, something like (pseudocode):

```
private void CheckAllCheckboxes(checkbox ACheckbox) //ACheckbox is the checkbox just clicked
{
    bool JustChecked = ACheckbox.checked; //did you enable or disable ACheckbox?
    for (int i = 0; i <= AllCheckBoxes.count; i++)
    {
        if (AllCheckboxes[i] != ACheckbox) //every checkbox except the one just checked...
        {
            AllCheckBoxes[i].checked = !JustChecked //set the opposite
        }
    }
}
```